# Switch htaccess file according to domain

Tags: .htaccess

is it possible to use different .htaccess files according to domain?

E.g.

```
if sub.domain.com, use .htaccess.sub
if domain.com, use .htaccess.main
```

or something like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up the subdomain in `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
DocumentRoot /home/httpd/htdocs/subdomain/
#You can put RewriteEngine here, or whatever "apachey" stuff you want to use
</VirtualHost>
```

Or INSIDE the `.htaccess` itself you can specify conditions like `RewriteCond` for example.

Note: You can **not** do something like this with `.htaccess`

```
IF SUBDOMAIN = 'something.domain.com'
THEN load/include/use .different_htaccess
```

Comment: The subdomains are pointing all to the same folder. I know about Conditions, but would be easier to have seperate files.

Comment: @Ilyssis: Well, you can't include files in `.htaccess`. What are the conditions you've tried so far?

Comment: Its not a problem with the conditions... just a question of clarity. But thanks...